# How to access members on a C++ reference or pointer in a Metal kernel?

Tags: c++, ios, gpu, metal

I always get the same error when trying to actually use references from any address space (constant, device, or thread). This does not compile, and gives an odd error:

```
struct Foo {
    int getter() const {
        return 1;
    }
};

void use_foo(constant Foo& foo) {
    int x = foo.getter(); // error here
}

kernel void test_kernel(constant Foo& foo [[buffer(0)]]) {
    use_foo(foo);
}
```

The error is:

> cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const Foo' with an expression of type 'const constant Foo'

Replace `constant` with any other memory address specifier, and it's the same general error. Doesn't matter if it was a reference passed into the kernel directly or a thread-local reference created by a function -- I cannot actually use these references in any way due to this error. Whether they are const or non-const references also makes no difference.

The only workaround is to just take a copy of `Foo` instead of trying to use a reference to it. I've never understood this odd error. I've also tried taking the argument as `constant const Foo&` and other trials and errors.

Can anyone advise how to actually use a reference?

I get a similar error if I switch to using a pointer instead of a reference:

[image]

from this:

```
struct Foo {
    int getter() const {
        return 1;
    }
};

void use_foo(constant const Foo* const foo) {
    int x = foo->getter(); // error here
}

kernel void test_kernel(constant Foo* foo [[buffer(0)]]) {
    use_foo(foo);
}
```

Similar attempts to experiment around using `const` or not in different places make no difference.

Comment: Just a guess, but is it possible to qualify the method `int getter() const constant` ?

Comment: Wow @jtbandes that was indeed a good guess, one I had not tried yet. And it worked! have you seen this kind of issue before? How did you know to try that?! The only issue is that if the member function is not going to be used on a `constant const` reference, then I need an identical overload without the added `constant`, or similar errors appear. But that is resolved, amazing.

Comment: I guessed this because usually in c++ there's a requirement that qualifications on the "receiver" ("'this' argument") of a member function must be qualified like the function itself, i.e. on a `const Foo` you can call `int getter() const` but not `int getter()`, and on a `Foo&&` you can call `int getter() &&` but not `int getter() &`. The part I didn't know was that it's actually allowed to include `constant` as one of these qualifications. Also… I [worked on a related error message](https://reviews.llvm.org/D39937) a while back as a side project :)

Comment: This is astonishing. Nice inference, @jtbandes!

Comment: I do see that this would be painful if it forces you to declare an identical overload. Can you call a `constant` member function on a `device` or other non-`constant` object? I think @warrenm has probably written the book on this, though, and might have more informed guesses than I ;)

Comment: One more thought: it's probably worth filing a bug report for the poor error message you got, which didn't really explain the actual problem.

Comment: Continuing the monologue: It actually looks like the error message you got was produced from a version of the code prior to the patch I linked. Likely the Metal compiler is maintained as a fork of Clang and never merged in my change from 2017. I have to wonder if this error message would've been better if they had taken my patch, since the compiler might've reminded them to update that code if they were adding a new type of `BadConversionSequence` ;)

Comment: @jtbandes to answer your question, you cannot call a `constant` member function on anything other than a `constant` object, same for the other types. they are distinct places in memory and compiler doesn't allow it unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [member function's qualifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) must generally match the type of the callee object. If you want to call such a method on a `const constant` object, you can qualify your method as such:

```
    int getter() const constant {
        return 1;
    }
```

The [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) says (§4): *"Any variable that is a pointer or reference must be declared with [device, constant, thread, threadgroup, or threadgroup_imageblock]"*. It's important to understand that the `this` argument to a member function is a pointer—basically an invisible function argument—and the qualifications on the function affect the type of that pointer. Effectively you are declaring `int getter(const constant Foo* this)`.

Comment: thanks again, really learned a lot on this question from your comments!