# What does the qualifier/keyword "thread" mean at the end of a metal (MSL) function?

Tags: metal

How can I understand what the keyword `thread` does in a metal shader language (MSL) function? I know that "all arguments to a graphics or kernel function that are a pointer or reference to a type must be declared with an address space attribute" and that `thread` is one of those adress spaces. `thread` refers to the per-thread memory address space and variables allocated in this adress space and not visible to other threads. Moreover, the reference says that "Variables declared inside a graphics or kernel function are allocated in the thread address space.". So far so good.

Now, what confuses me is that if you look at the signatures of the standard library, you will find that `thread` also appears at the *end* of member functions. For example, let's look a `ray` from the standard library (`METAL_FUNC` just means always inline):

```
struct ray
{
  METAL_FUNC ray(float3 origin = 0.0f, float3 direction = 0.0f, float min_distance = 0.0f, float max_distance = INFINITY) thread
      : origin(origin),
        direction(direction),
        min_distance(min_distance),
        max_distance(max_distance)
  {
  }
  METAL_FUNC ray(const thread ray &) thread = default;
  METAL_FUNC thread ray &operator=(const thread ray &) thread = default;

  float3 origin;
  float3 direction;
  float min_distance;
  float max_distance;
};
```

For instance on the default copy constructor

```
METAL_FUNC ray(const thread ray &) thread = default;
```

The parameter argument is a const reference to a ray (in the same calling thread, right?). What does `thread` at *the end* do? what happens if we omit it?

On the other hand, see the default copy assignment operator. Where does the returning ray reference live? is it in a different thread address space?

Comment: I don't know the Metal shading language, but its constructs look like they are directly derived from C++. In C++, qualifiers like `const` at the end of member functions apply to the `this` parameter. So I imagine that's how it works in MSL too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access members on a C++ reference or pointer in a Metal kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447945/how-to-access-members-on-a-c-reference-or-pointer-in-a-metal-kernel)

Comment: Both of your comments go to the right point! After your comments, I found this very instructive example https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695653

Comment: One thing to notice is that I do not get a compile error if I forget/omit the `thread` qualifier at the end of a member function. This is strange as the reference says "If an address space attribute is missing on a pointer or reference type declaration, a compilation error occurs."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metal supports additional overloading on address spaces of argument. it is specified after member functions for current object(this):

[image]

from 1.4.1 https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf